# Serverless framework with localstack fails deployment on creating request template in aws-nodejs-typescript example

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, docker-compose, serverless, localstack

Setup localstack + serverless framework fails at creating a model request for the example lambda code generated via the `serverless create --template aws-nodejs-typescript` command. After creating the project I added the necessary code to it, responsible for integration with localstack along with installation of serverless-localstack plugin.

serverless.ts

```js
import type {AWS} from '@serverless/typescript';

import hello from '@functions/hello';

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
    service: 'aws-serverless-typescript-api',
    frameworkVersion: '3',
    plugins: ['serverless-esbuild', 'serverless-localstack'],
    provider: {
        name: 'aws',
        runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
        apiGateway: {
            minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
            shouldStartNameWithService: true,
        },
        environment: {
            AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
            NODE_OPTIONS: '--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000',
        },
    },
    // import the function via paths
    functions: {hello},
    package: {individually: true},
    custom: {
        esbuild: {
            bundle: true,
            minify: false,
            sourcemap: true,
            exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
            target: 'node14',
            define: {'require.resolve': undefined},
            platform: 'node',
            concurrency: 10,
        },
        localstack: {
            stages: ['local'],
            host: 'http://localhost',
            edgePort: 4566,
            autostart: true,
            bundle: true,
            minify: false,
            sourcemap: true,
            exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
            target: 'node16',
            define: {'require.resolve': undefined},
            platform: 'node',
            concurrency: 10,
        },
    },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - DEBUG=1
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - '4566-4583:4566-4583'
    volumes:
      - "${TEMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Code related to lambda function:
index.ts

```js
import schema from './schema';
import { handlerPath } from '@libs/handler-resolver';

export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  events: [
    {
      http: {
        method: 'post',
        path: 'hello',
        request: {
          schemas: {
            'application/json': schema,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

schema.ts

```js
export default {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    name: { type: 'string' }
  },
  required: ['name']
} as const;
```

handler.ts

```js
import type { ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { formatJSONResponse } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { middyfy } from '@libs/lambda';

import schema from './schema';

const hello: ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<typeof schema> = async (event) => {
  return formatJSONResponse({
    message: `Hello ${event.body.name}, welcome to the exciting Serverless world!`,
    event,
  });
};

export const main = middyfy(hello);
```

When running `serverless deploy --stage local` the output I receive is:

```
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  | 2023-06-05T12:27:03.136 DEBUG --- [functhread51] l.s.c.e.template_deployer  : Running action "create" for resource type "AWS::ApiGateway::Method" id "ApiGatewayMethodHelloPost"
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  | 2023-06-05T12:27:03.136 DEBUG --- [functhread51] l.s.c.e.template_deployer  : Request for resource type "AWS::ApiGateway::Method" in region us-east-1: put_method {'restApiId': 'kkfffdr364', 'resourceId': '3zd2vykhzn', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'apiKeyRequired': False, 'authorizationType': 'NONE', 'requestParameters': {}, 'requestModels': {'application/json': '2d8148'}, 'requestValidatorId': 'c5e1d0'}
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  | 2023-06-05T12:27:03.140  WARN --- [functhread51] l.s.c.e.template_deployer  : Error calling <bound method ClientCreator._create_api_method.<locals>._api_call of <botocore.client.APIGateway object at 0xffff53d7b100>> with params: {'restApiId': 'kkfffdr364', 'resourceId': '3zd2vykhzn', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'apiKeyRequired': False, 'authorizationType': 'NONE', 'requestParameters': {}, 'requestModels': {'application/json': '2d8148'}, 'requestValidatorId': 'c5e1d0'} for resource: {'Type': 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method', 'DependsOn': ['HelloLambdaPermissionApiGateway'], 'LogicalResourceId': 'ApiGatewayMethodHelloPost', 'Properties': {'HttpMethod': 'POST', 'RequestParameters': {}, 'ResourceId': '3zd2vykhzn', 'RestApiId': 'kkfffdr364', 'ApiKeyRequired': False, 'AuthorizationType': 'NONE', 'Integration': {'IntegrationHttpMethod': 'POST', 'Type': 'AWS_PROXY', 'Uri': 'arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:aws-serverless-typescript-api-local-hello/invocations'}, 'MethodResponses': [], 'RequestValidatorId': 'c5e1d0', 'RequestModels': {'application/json': '2d8148'}}, '_state_': {}}
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  | 2023-06-05T12:27:03.141 DEBUG --- [functhread51] l.s.c.e.template_deployer  : Error applying changes for CloudFormation stack "aws-serverless-typescript-api-local": An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutMethod operation: Invalid model identifier specified: 2d8148 Traceback (most recent call last):
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/engine/template_deployer.py", line 1409, in _run
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |     self.do_apply_changes_in_loop(changes, stack)
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/engine/template_deployer.py", line 1489, in do_apply_changes_in_loop
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |     self.apply_change(change, stack=stack)
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/engine/template_deployer.py", line 1575, in apply_change
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |     result = execute_resource_action(
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/engine/template_deployer.py", line 820, in execute_resource_action
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |     result = invoke_function(
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/engine/template_deployer.py", line 868, in invoke_function
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |     raise e
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/engine/template_deployer.py", line 851, in invoke_function
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |     result = function(**params)
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 964, in _make_api_call
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  |     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
aws-serverless-typescript-api-localstack-1  | botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutMethod operation: Invalid model identifier specified: 2d8148
```

This error occurs only with lambdas that have a schemas block defined and accept parameters.